# Deep NN architecture for predicting a matrix from a matrix and list of floats

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to predict a matrix (size `RxC`) based on an input matrix (size `RxC`) and a list of floats `L` (length `P`). Essentially, I am trying to create an ML model to replace ray-tracing simulation. For each `L`, ray-tracing software will spend about 20-30 mins to generate a new matrix, so I was thinking of by-passing the ray-tracing by training an NN to predict the new matrix using a base-line input matrix and a list of float that contains the deviation of ray-tracing parameters from the base-line value.

There is a spatial relationship in the matrix i.e `M[0,0]` has a relationship with `M[1,1]`. But since I will also have a list of float as an input, I don't think using CNN will work, won't it?

Is there any known architecture to complete this task?

I am thinking to flatten the input (input dimension becomes `R*C+P`) and the output layer will also be flattened (dimension `R*C`).

Thanks a lot and any suggestion will be appreciated! Cheers!